# Spring Boot RestTemplate throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [http://test.com?value=Dummy text #test] is not a valid URI

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, get, resttemplate

I am trying to call a REST GET endpoint using RestTemplate in Spring Boot. In URL there is query parameter which contains # in its value. I have tried URL encoding but its not working with RestTemplate.

```
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(base64CredentialsBytes));

    HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<Map> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://test.com?value=Dummy text #test", HttpMethod.GET, request, Map.class);
```

Above functions throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [http://test.com?value=Dummy text #test] is not a valid URI. But, it works if # is not the part of request parameter.
Looking for a way to include special characters like # in request params of Resttemplate

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is not encoded. it should look like this:

```
http://test.com?value=Dummy%20text%20%23test
```

Please read more about URL encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Tried that but, the thing is that value parameter is shown on the chat box.If I encode the value then it prints value text in encoded form in chatbox.

Comment: What is test.com?

Comment: test.com just an instance as I can't expose the actual host due to some security reasons

Comment: so then the receiver does not url decode the parameter